# Certificate pinning in IBM MobileFirst Platform

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, certificate-pinning

What are the checks that will be performed when we call the method `WL.Client.pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey` for MobileFirst hybrid app ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355610/lack-of-certificate-pinning-in-ibm-mobile-first-platform-7-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all explained in the documentation. See here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/monitor/c_cert_pinning_intro.html

> Certificate pinning is the process of associating a host with its expected public key. Because you own both the server-side code and the client-side code, you can configure your client code to accept only a specific certificate for your domain name, instead of any certificate that corresponds to a trusted CA root certificate recognized by the operating system or browser.
>
> A copy of the certificate is placed in your client application. During the SSL handshake (first request to the server), the IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation for iOS client SDK verifies that the public key of the server certificate matches the public key of the certificate that is stored 
>   in the app.
>
> If pinning is successful, the public key inside the provided certificate is used to verify the integrity of the MobileFirst Server certificate during the secured request SSL/TLS handshake. If pinning fails, all SSL/TLS requests to the server are rejected by the client application.

The API initiates the pinning process.